# How does $(eMe)m_1(eMe) = (eMe)m_2(eMe) \Rightarrow Mm_1M = Mm_2M$?

Tags: monoid, greens-relations

I am studying the book "Representation Theory of Finite Monoids" by Benjamin Steinberg, I've tried searching online for the solution but I don't know how to search for it so google shows no results. In Lemma 1.7 the author says that is clear that:

Given an idempotent, $e$, of a finite monoid $M$ and $m_1, m_2 \in eMe$:
$$
(eMe)m_1(eMe) = (eMe)m_2(eMe) \Rightarrow Mm_1M = Mm_2M
$$
but I can't figure it out.

I can see how $(eMe)m_1(eMe) = (eMe)m_2(eMe) \Rightarrow eMm_1Me = eMm_2Me$ but then I get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that if $m \in eMe$, then $eme = m$.
Now, let $m_1, m_2 \in eMe$ and suppose that
$$
(eMe)m_1(eMe) = (eMe)m_2(eMe)
$$
Then
$$
m_1 = eeem_1eee \in (eMe)m_1(eMe) = (eMe)m_2(eMe) \subseteq Mm_2M
$$
and similarly $m_2 \in Mm_1M$. It follows that $Mm_1M = Mm_2M$.